# else condition not working when reader hasrows is false

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, sqldatareader

Can somebody tell me why the else condition is not working in the code below.

The link button in asp.net web application has following code in code behind: a parameterized `SqlCommand` fetch a row from a SQL Server database, the `SqlDataReader rdr1.HasRows` in if condition is working fine but else condition did not work.

***Code updated***

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string comid = DropDownList4.SelectedValue.ToString();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Commercials Where id =" + comid, con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string dur = rdr["duration"].ToString();
            Char delimiter = '/';
            string[] dd = DateTime.Parse(rdr["rodate"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Split(delimiter);

            if (DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains("BOL NEWS") == true && DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains("After Headlines") == true)
            {
                SqlConnection con0 = new SqlConnection(cs);
                string sql01 = "Select * from CTS Where air_time=(Select max(air_time) from CTS where air_date=@airdate and air_time Like @airtime and channel=@channel and Slot=@slot) and air_date=@airdate1";
                con0.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql01, con0);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@airdate", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@channel", DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString());
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@airtime", DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, 2) + "%");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slot", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Remove(0, 3));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@airdate1", TextBox1.Text);

                SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr1.Read())
                {
                    string startTime0 = rdr1["air_time"].ToString();
                    string addsec = rdr1["duration"].ToString();

                    if (rdr1.HasRows)
                    {
                        DateTime startTime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime0, "HH:mm:ss", null);
                        string startHeadlines_ = startTime1.AddSeconds(int.Parse(addsec)).ToString("HH:mm:ss");

                        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(cs))
                        {
                            string type = "Commercial";
                            string year = dd[2].ToString().Substring(dd[2].ToString().Length - 2);
                            string HouseId = "CH1COM001" + rdr["rono"] + rdr["duration"] + "S" + dd[1] + dd[0] + year;
                            string sql1 = "Insert into CTS(air_date,air_time,HouseNumber,rono,Title,duration,Slot,type,channel)Values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + startHeadlines_ + "','" + HouseId + "','" + rdr["rono"] + "','" + rdr["slug"] + "','" + rdr["duration"] + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Remove(0, 3) + "','" + type + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";

                            con2.Open();

                            SqlCommand InsertCmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, con2);
                            InsertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            con2.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        DateTime startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", null);
                        string startHeadlines = startTime.AddSeconds(210).ToString("HH:mm:ss");

                        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(cs))
                        {
                            string type = "Commercial";
                            string year = dd[2].ToString().Substring(dd[2].ToString().Length - 2);
                            string HouseId = "CH1COM001" + rdr["rono"] + rdr["duration"] + "S" + dd[1] + dd[0] + year;
                            string sql = "Insert into CTS(air_date,air_time,HouseNumber,rono,Title,duration,Slot,type,channel)Values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + startHeadlines + "','" + HouseId + "','" + rdr["rono"] + "','" + rdr["slug"] + "','" + rdr["duration"] + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Remove(0, 3) + "','" + type + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";

                            con1.Open();

                            SqlCommand InsertCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con1);
                            InsertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            con1.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                con0.Close();
            }
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean “did not work”. If/else statements work fine.  You’ll need to be more explicit about what behavior you are seeing and what behavior you expected to see if we’re going to be able to help.

Comment: I mean if the reader has rows the if condition executes but when reader has no rows the else portion did not executes as expected i.e new record can not be inserted in the database through else statement While when condition is true the if condition succesfully insert the record in the database

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way. First you should check if DataReader Has Rows and then you should do a DataReader.Read().

Comment: Thanks Gagan for pointing out my mistake, great help indeed